# Parse.com & Android: How do i delete a row on Parse.com from my ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I have a parse.com database that I use to fill a List View row. It works like this. Every time a user posts something new, a new row is added to the Parse.com class. I would like to have the application prompt the user on long click if he would like the post to be deleted. If he chooses yes then the post is deleted from the list view as well as parse.com. I have not included my layout files but if you need them i could post. Here are my codes:

CHAT ACTIVITY:(Displays all messages sent)

public class ChatActivity extends ListActivity {

```
protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;
protected Button mPost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    mPost=(Button)findViewById(R.id.postChat);
    mPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(ChatActivity.this,MessageActivity.class);
            ChatActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ParseUser currentUser=ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser!=null)
    //Event for filling list view
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Chat");
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> status, ParseException e) {
                if(e==null)
                {//Event for a successful post
                    mStatus=status;
                    ChatAdapter adapter=new ChatAdapter(getListView().getContext(),mStatus);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else
                {//Event for a failed post

                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    //Event in case user is not logged on
    {   Intent main = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        ChatActivity.this.startActivity(main);
        ChatActivity.this.finish();}
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //switch for menu events
    switch(id)
    {case R.id.LogoutChatMenu:
        {//logout the user
            ParseUser.logOut();
            //Take user back to login
            Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            ChatActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            ChatActivity.this.finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGOUT SUCCESSFUL.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;}}

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
    ParseObject statusObject=mStatus.get(position);
    String objectId=statusObject.getObjectId();

    Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, ChatDetailView.class);
    intent.putExtra("objectId",objectId);
    ChatActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

CHAT ADAPTER (an adapter to handle populating the ListView)

public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
protected Context mContext;
protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;

//Status adapter for the list view
public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> Chat) {
    super(context, R.layout.chatcustomlayout, Chat);
    mContext = context;
    mStatus = Chat;
}

//Event to fill each row of the list view
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //Event to create a new view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.chatcustomlayout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //Adds username to holder
        holder.usernameProfile = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.usernameCustom);
        //Adds status to holder
        holder.statusProfile = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.statusCustom);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        //Event for a view that already exists
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    ParseObject statusObject = mStatus.get(position);

    // Display username in holder
    String username = statusObject.getString("User");
    holder.usernameProfile.setText(username);

    // Display status in holder
    String status = statusObject.getString("newStatus");
    holder.statusProfile.setText(status);

    return convertView;
}
//Initialising variables
public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView usernameProfile;
    TextView statusProfile;

}
```

}

MESSAGE ACTIVITY:(Used to type message and send)

public class MessageActivity extends Activity {

```
protected EditText mUpdateStatus;
protected Button mUpdateStatusButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

    //initialization of variables
    mUpdateStatus=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageMessage);
    mUpdateStatusButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);

    //code update button click event
    mUpdateStatusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Get current user
            ParseUser currentUser=ParseUser.getCurrentUser();//Identifies current user
            String currentUserUsername=currentUser.getUsername();//stores username in variable

            //Create new variable to store strings
            String newStatus=mUpdateStatus.getText().toString();

            //Event for an empty status
            if (newStatus.isEmpty())
            {AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MessageActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("STATUS SHOULD NOT BE EMPTY.");
                builder.setTitle("OOPS!");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
                dialog.show();}
            else{
                //Save the status in Parse.com
                ParseObject statusObject = new ParseObject("Chat");//Create a new parse class
                statusObject.put("newStatus",newStatus);//Creates a new attribute and adds value from newStatus
                statusObject.put("User",currentUserUsername);//Stores username in new parse class

                //Save data and initiate callback method
                statusObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if(e==null)
                        {//Event for a Successful storage
                            Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this,"MESSAGE SENT.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            //Take user back to profile
                            Intent main = new Intent(MessageActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
                            MessageActivity.this.startActivity(main);

                        }
                        else
                        {//Event for an Unsuccessful storage
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MessageActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                            builder.setTitle("SORRY!");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });}

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_message, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    switch(id) {
        case R.id.logoutMessageMenu:
        {//logout the user
            ParseUser.logOut();
            //Take user back to login
            Intent intent = new Intent(MessageActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            MessageActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            MessageActivity.this.finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGOUT SUCCESSFUL.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;}
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ParseObject.createWithoutData("YourClassName","objectId").deleteEventually();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it by using its object id but when it comes to deleting it from the list view you have to create a methode called refresh post list that is implemented after delete that removes all the items from the list view and query them from parse.com table to the list view